# Does FB.init with xfbml: true insert a Facebook like button into elements that aren't tagged with FBML?

Tags: facebook-like

We have a number of pages (some in production) with working Facebook Like buttons that started to render a **second**, default Like button a day or so ago, with no code changes on our part!

Screenshot of working Like/Share buttons (as of a couple of days ago):

[image: working]

Screenshot of extra Like button, above the intended Like/Share buttons (happening now):

[image: broken]

After digging into it, it looks like the behavior of Facebook's JavaScript code has changed, s.t. a `span` element with a class of `fb-like` is getting a Like button inserted when we call `FB.init` with `xfbml: true`:

```
FB.init({appId: 'FACEBOOK_APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
```

I think this call *should* only parse FBML elements (e.g., `fb:like` tags), but we insert those dynamically, after the page loads (by which time, there is already a default Like button in the DOM).

To verify this, when I changed the class of the `span` in our DOM to `fsfb-like`, the extra Like button does *not* get rendered. Calling `FB.init` with `xfbml: false` also does not render the extra Like button.

We're assuming that Facebook's JavaScript is broken (temporarily, we hope). Is this a safe assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was caused by a change in Facebook's JavaScript, and has been fixed for external (non-Facebook apps) web sites, but remains for (at least some) Facebook apps (e.g., [this FanSnap app](http://apps.facebook.com/whosgoingbyfansnap/san-francisco-49ers-tickets/pittsburgh-steelers-vs-san-francisco-49ers/december-19-2011-629366)).

I'm hoping that Facebook will also fix this problem for Facebook apps.